# Converting pdf files to txt files with php

Tags: php, pdf, text-files

There's this program, pdftotext, that can convert a pdf file to a text file. To use it directly on the linux console:

```
pdftotext file.pdf
```

That will generate a file.txt on the same directory as the pdf file. I was looking for a way to do it from inside a php program, and after some googling I ended with two commands that should work for me: *system()* and *exec()*. So I made a php file with this:

```
<?php
    system('pdftotext file.pdf');
?>
```

But when I run this code, it doesn't work. No txt file is created.
So I tried to create a test file with another command:

```
<?php
    system('touch test.txt');
?>
```

This worked fine. I've also used exec() and the results were the same. Why doesn't it work?

**EDIT:** following RoBorg advice, i added the 2>&1 argument to the command, so:

```
<?php
    system('pdftotext file.pdf 2>&1');
?>
```

it printed a error message:

> pdftotext: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

Seems like something is missing on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably a permissions issue, but try this instead:

```
<?php
    system('pdftotext file.pdf 2>&1');
?>
```

The `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout, so any error messages will be printed.  It should be pretty easy to fix from then on.

Comment: it printed a error message
"pdftotext: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory "
since i dont have root access to the server, i guess there's nothing i can do.

Answer (score 0):

install this.  it solved the problem for me.

http://www.ssforge.com/ssforge-standard/onlinehelp/help/faq/libstdc.html

now, pdftotext works great.

Comment: The page is 404 since 2014 and SSForge is no more since 2020.

Answer (score -1):

PHP has a build in PDF function library, that should be able to give you what you need:
https://www.php.net/pdf

Comment: Seems like that library is mainly for outputting pdf. What i need is the other way around